# PHP 5.3 on Linux, how to enable MSSQL support for mssql_connect() function

Tags: sql-server, linux, php-5.3

I have tried installing `php53-mssql` via `yum` and reloading Apache, but `mssql_connect()` returns `undefined function` in the Apache log.  How can I get MSSQL support to work easily?  Red Hat Linux 5.8

Comment: Try restarting instead of reloading?

Comment: I did restart as well.  I think it installed modules to /usr/lib/php/modules instead of /usr/lib64/php/modules simply copying the .so files doesnt work.  Wong ELF class error.

Comment: Have you downloaded the 32bit version when you need the 64bit?

Comment: Yes that seems to be part of the problem, but for whatever reason the Yum repo gives me this binary, when I know I am x86_64